# How to parse JSON data set from a defined HTML Javascript block using Python?

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some online sales data from from https://www.timbuk2.com/collections/sale. I am able to narrow it down to extract the script block that contains the JSON data set, but I am struggle to extract the json data.

Here's what I have so far

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://www.timbuk2.com/collections/sale'
response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

scripts = soup(text=re.compile(r'products:'))[0].parent
print(scripts)
```

My goal here is to parse out the BOLD.collection_filter.config dictionary

```
BOLD.collection_filter.config = {
      products: [{
    "order":0,
    "id":1431161864234,
    "title":"Command Messenger Bag",
    "vendor":"Timbuk2-Sale",
    "type": "Messenger","tags": ["category-Messenger","collections-bestsellers","collections-bike","collections-work","gender-Mens","gender-Womens","madetype-Finished Good","site-Sale","product_type-Messenger","occasions-Bike","occasions-Travel","occasions-Work"],
    "handle": "174-command-messenger-bag-sale","image": "1/2572/9458/products/timbuk2-messenger-command-messenger-bag-nautical-adobe_174-4-7480_front-sale-ffe38181818183ff-1989.jpg?v=1539383378","created_at": "2018-04-20 15:14:13 -0700",
    "published_at": "2018-04-20 15:14:13 -0700","image_aspect_ratio": "1.2006003001500751",
    "image_width":2400,
    "image_height":1999,
    "option_values":[["S","Midway"],["M","Jet Black"],["M","Midway"],["M","Surplus"],["M","Black\/Gunmetal"],["M","Carbon Full-Cycle Twill"],["M","Black\/Red Devil"],["M","Abyss"],["M","Carbon and Molasses"],["M","Oxide and Adobe"],["L","Midway"],["M","Nautical\/Adobe"]],
    "options":["Size","Color"],
    "insights":null,"variants": [
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First get a string that is valid JSON. Fiddle around with an online JSON formatter (eg. https://jsonformatter.org/ )

The following is valid JSON:

```
{
    "products": [{
    "order":0,
    "id":1431161864234,
    "title":"Command Messenger Bag",
    "vendor":"Timbuk2-Sale",
    "type": "Messenger","tags": ["category-Messenger","collections-bestsellers","collections-bike","collections-work","gender-Mens","gender-Womens","madetype-Finished Good","site-Sale","product_type-Messenger","occasions-Bike","occasions-Travel","occasions-Work"],
    "handle": "174-command-messenger-bag-sale","image": "1/2572/9458/products/timbuk2-messenger-command-messenger-bag-nautical-adobe_174-4-7480_front-sale-ffe38181818183ff-1989.jpg?v=1539383378","created_at": "2018-04-20 15:14:13 -0700",
    "published_at": "2018-04-20 15:14:13 -0700","image_aspect_ratio": "1.2006003001500751",
    "image_width":2400,
    "image_height":1999,
    "option_values":[["S","Midway"],["M","Jet Black"],["M","Midway"],["M","Surplus"],["M","Black\/Gunmetal"],["M","Carbon Full-Cycle Twill"],["M","Black\/Red Devil"],["M","Abyss"],["M","Carbon and Molasses"],["M","Oxide and Adobe"],["L","Midway"],["M","Nautical\/Adobe"]],
    "options":["Size","Color"]
}]
}
```

So maybe adapt your regular expression a little bit.

Then use

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

data = json.loads(your_string)

pprint(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question appear to ask how to extract how a specific javascrip variable.
Try this with other examples

```
scripts = soup(text=re.compile(r'products:'))[0].parent
variable_name = "BOLD.collection_filter.config"
re.search(r"(?<=%s).*?(\{.*)(?=\;|<\/script>)"%variable_name,str(scripts),re.S).group(1)
```